# jQuery scroll makes sticky header jump a bit

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, header

I have a problem with sticky header and navigation links, since they both use **scrollTop** functions.

First one is for a header - it shrinks down when page is being scrolled after 50px.
Second one is used with navigation links - it uses scroll function to go to certain page.

Problems is when I click any navigation link, my logo jumps / blinks for a bit and I'm not sure why is that happening? I've recreated this problem in JSFiddle (link down bellow) and this is the code:

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <a class="pg1 btn" href="#">Page1</a>
  <a class="pg2 btn" href="#">Page2</a>
</nav>
<article class="home">
  <img class="logoHomePage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150.jpg">
</article>
<article class="page1"></article>
<article class="page2"></article>
```

jQuery:

```
// Shrink logo
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) {
    $(".logoHomePage").addClass("smallLogo");
  } else {
    $(".logoHomePage").removeClass("smallLogo");
  }
});

//nav
$(".pg1.btn").click(function() {
  $("body").animate(
    {
      scrollTop: $(".page1").offset().top
    },
    1200
  );
});

$(".pg2.btn").click(function() {
  $("body").animate(
    {
      scrollTop: $(".page2").offset().top
    },
    1200
  );
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

article {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
}

.logoHomePage {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 25%;
}

.smallLogo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 260px;
  margin: 10px !important;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
}
nav {
  z-index: 20;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
}

.page1 {
  background: green;
}

.page2 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Fiddle for reference: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dL3gvmv/)

**Edit: click on page1 link and than on page2 to see it in action.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glitch happens because the page wants to jump to the top of the page, which is expected behaviour when you put the empty anchor `#` as href. It points to the top of the page.

Use `.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behaviour of a link ([documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)). Like so:

```
$(".pg1.btn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $("body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(".page1").offset().top
  }, 1200);
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dL3gvmv/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that about #, thanks again!